# Return values from table a only if it contains corresponding IDs in table b

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried searching for an answer, but its hard to ask the question or formulate a search to find an answer. So here goes.

I have table A where I store client information, and table B where I store client requests. I am building a search thingy where I want to search for the clients WHERE Bob has helped. Which becomes tricky as I only want 1 row returned per client that Bob has helped. Using a normal join would return multiple rows as there are more than one requests where Bob has helped that client.

See table structure below. (cant add images yet :( )

[image: Table setup]

For example, the below query returns multiple rows (5, as there 5 requests attended to by Bob).

```
SELECT a.ClientName, b.AttendedBy
FROM TableA A 
JOIN TableB b ON a.ClientId = b.ClientId
WHERE b.AttendedBy = 'Peter'
```

So the results I want is below:

[image: Results]

If I want to know which clients Peter attended to then results 1, if I want to know which clients Andrew attended to, then results 2. If I search 'Michael', then NO results must be returned for the client. So nothing basically. Only Show the Client where the 'attendedBy' exists in the client requests (table b).

I have tried multiple things, such as DISTINCT SELECT IN the WHEREclause, STUFF() function, TOP 1, LIMIT, but I am not winning. Assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

edit:
p.s, table B and B have other columns with unique values, so using DISTINCT will still return multiple rows for the same client where Peter attended.

Comment: Is it bob or is it peter?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you simply want `select distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ClientName, b.AttendedBy
FROM TableA A JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.ClientId = b.ClientId
WHERE b.AttendedBy = 'Peter'
```

Comment: Correct, but those are not the only values in table b. There is also a column called query type which is unique. So each row has a different query type which is seen as DISTINCT and still returns CLIENT several times. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: you mean,for each client request in table B there is a unique value that you wanted to display with the result set right?If that is the case obviously client id will get repeat,right? also can you please include the  additional columns in you sample input and output table mentioned above?so we will get an idea on your requirement.

Comment: So i do not want to display the additional columns or unique values in table B. the only thing i require from table b to display is the attendedBy. I might be onto something now. Will comment shortly. 

what i am doing is saying 

SELECT a .ClientName, b.AttendedBy 
FROM TableA A JOIN
           TableB b
           ON a.ClientId = b.ClientId

WHERE ClientId IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ClientId) FROM Table B
     WHERE AttendedBy = 'Peter')

Comment: @RaymondBarreto . . . This query only selects two columns -- as you have asked in your question.  Other columns will not affect the answer.  If you have a different question, then you should ask it as a *new* question, particularly because this question already has answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.ClientName, b.AttendedBy,concat('Result',rank over(order by a.clientName))
FROM TableA A JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.ClientId = b.ClientId
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

But I managed to get it. I did the following:

```
SELECT a.ClientName, b.AttendedBy
FROM TableA A 
JOIN TableB b ON a.ClientId = b.ClientId
WHERE a.ClientId IN (SELECT DISTINCT ClientId FROM Table B WHERE AttendedBy = 'Peter')
```